# Slide panel in C# winforms just like jquery SlideToggle

Tags: c#, jquery, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Platform : C#
IDE: Visual Studio 2010

Is it possible to toggle panel on button click, just like the functionality of slideToggle in Jquery, without using threading concept ?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795005/add-an-expander-collapse-expand-to-a-panel-winform

Comment: Yes !!! Something like this ...